# calling Javascript function in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm trying to call a function and activate an alert through it in my JSP.
This is what i've done so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

function myFunction( test )
{
    alert( test );
}
</script>
<title>Success</title>
</head>
<body>
     <c:set var="test" scope="request" value="${requestScope.userDetails }"></c:set>
     <input type="button" id="sample_button" onclick="myFunction(${test.userName})" value="test">
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to that, You might also need to add a single quote inside the calling function

```
<input type="button" id="sample_button" onclick="myFunction('${test.userName}')" value="test">
```

Check for javascript errors & verify the generated HTML in browser

Answer (score 1):

You had a `meta` element inside `script` element which will throw an error while parsing the script block

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function myFunction( test )
            {
            alert( test );
            }
        </script>
        <title>Success</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:set var="test" scope="request" value="${requestScope.userDetails }"></c:set>
        <input type="button" id="sample_button" onclick="myFunction(${test.userName})" value="test" />
    </body>
</html>
```